# ANT Error in Identifying the Correct Java Package

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build

I'm using Eclipse and I have a build.xml within the directory:
C:\Users\my_user\eclipse_workspace\MyApplication\directory_a\EJB\EJBName1\build.xml

```
<javac debug="true" debuglevel="source,lines,vars" destdir="bin/compile" source="1.5" target="1.5" encoding="iso-8859-1">
<src path="src" />
</javac>
```

When I run the script I got the ff error:

```
[javac] C:\Users\my_user\eclipse_workspace\MyApplication\directory_a\EJB\EJBName1\
src\com\company_name\app_name\data\manipulators\DataManipulator.java:1: 'class' or 'interface' expected
[javac] package com.company_name.app_name.data.manipulators;
        ^
```

What should I do so that the code or ANT build can correctly identify the package folder?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by adding the **include** tags after the **src** tag.

```
<javac debug="true" debuglevel="source,lines,vars" destdir="bin/compile" source="1.5" target="1.5" encoding="iso-8859-1">
<src path="src" />
<include name="com/company_name/app_name/data/**" />
<include name="com/company_name/app_name/package_a/**" />
<include name="com/company_name/app_name/package_c/**" />
</javac>
```